# HasChildNodes (.Net, XmlDocument ) always reported "true"

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I would like to distinguish these two cases - but HasChildNode returns in both cases "true" and the number of childNodes is 1 in both cases.

```
<eventid>45072</eventid>
<titles>
    <title>kabel eins late news</title>
</titles>
```

Here ist my sample code and output.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlString);
XmlNodeList xnList = doc.SelectNodes("/epg/programme");
foreach (XmlNode n in xnList) {          
    foreach (XmlNode n1 in n.ChildNodes) {
       if (n1.HasChildNodes) {
           AppendText($"n1 has {n1.ChildNodes.Count} ChildNodes");
           foreach (XmlNode n2 in n1.ChildNodes) {
              Append(41,n2.Name, n2.InnerText);
           }
       }
       else {
         // this will never called
          Append(46,n1.Name, n1.InnerText);
       }
   }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<epg Ver="1">
    <programme>
    <eventid>45072</eventid>
    <titles>
        <title>kabel eins late news</title>
    </titles>
   </programme>
</epg>
```

Output:

n1 has 1 ChildNodes
41:#text:45072
n1 has 1 ChildNodes
41:title:kabel eins late news

Comment: The text inside an Element is a Node, as are Attributes, etc.  If you update to net newer XDocument, XElement you can use XElement.HasElements. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.haselements(v=vs.110).aspx  Or you can enumerate the ChildNodes and see if any are Elements.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft That should be an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I have changed my code to XDocument and a little bit Linq to XML

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
    var programme = doc.Descendants("programme").Select(p => p);
    foreach (XElement p in programme) {
       foreach (var attr in p.Attributes()){
              AppendText($"{attr.Name} {attr.Value}");
       }
       foreach (XElement ele in p.Elements()) {
           if (ele.HasElements) {
               foreach (XElement child in ele.Elements()) {
                   AppendText($"{child.Name} {child.Value}");
               }
           }
           else {
               AppendText($"{ele.Name} {ele.Value}");
           }               
       }
    }
```

I found only a few beginner examples so here is this snippet for the start.